# Using ElementTree to find <key><string> information

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am very new to ET, but I can't find the simplest way to do this. I have an XML file with associated values that are not nested, I need to pull in the text from each one, and shove them into variables that I will later manipulate. the problem is knowing how to get each value.

Example XML:

```
<key>Creation Date</key>
    <date>2012-08-18T16:53:23Z</date>
    <key>Entry Text</key>
    <string>This is some entry text</string>
    <key>Location</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Administrative Area</key>
        <string>State</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>United States</string>
        <key>Latitude</key>
        <real>39.647493</real>
        <key>Locality</key>
        <string>City</string>
        <key>Longitude</key>
        <real>-84.11737579840</real>
        <key>Place Name</key>
        <string>123 street</string>
        <key>State</key>
        <string>auto</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Starred</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>0B38EF885FB84F647GHT738</string>
```

As you can see, the tags aren't really associated in an intelligent way. For example how would I get:

```
EntryText = [The <String> Text after <key> Entry Text]
```

so EntryText would = This is some entry text

or

```
country = [<key>Location <dict> <key> Country <string>]
```

so country = United States

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse the [OS X `.plist` XML data structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html). Python already comes with a module that can parse that for you; [`plistlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html). Use that instead:

```
import plistlib

result = plistlib.readPlist(filename)
print result['Entry Text']
```